# What is a good alternative to namespaces within classes?

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, scope

The problem is C++ does not allow namespace declarations within classes.(I searched on internet and found this; if it's not true, please say it) So, what's the best way to cheat this problem?

Context: My class have an enumeration within it.

```
class GameCharacter {
public:
    enum MovingState {
        Running,
        Walking,
        Stopped
    };
    ...
};
```

OBS: This example is not real, it's totally hypothetical.

C++ defines that the enumeration names are inside the class scope, then to use these states I have to use the scope operator directly from the class name(`GameCharacter::Running`, for instance; or `using GameCharacter::Running`).

I think this is bad, because the name which belongs to the enumeration is inside the class scope; I wanted to have a scope for the RunningState enumeration. (accessing it this way: `GameCharacter::MovingState::Running`)
My first thought, then, was to create a namespace which would define a scope for the enumeration.

```
class GameCharacter {
public:
    // does not compile
    namespace MovingState {
        enum State {
            Running,
            Walking,
            Stopped
        };
    };
    ...
};
```

But C++ forbids it. This code does not compile. (`main.cpp:3:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’`)

The reason why I'm trying to do things this way is because there is a possibility to create an second enumeration with names in same scope. Which could cause conflicting names.

```
class GameCharacter {
public:
    enum MovingState {
        Running,
        Walking,
        Stopped
    };
    enum DrivingState {
        Accelerating,
        Breaking,
        Stopped        // Compilation error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘GameCharacter::MovingState GameCharacter::Stopped’
    };
    ...
};
```

(my idea was that, in this case, the states should be referred as `GameCharacter::MovingState::Stopped` and `GameCharacter::DrivingState::Stopped`)
Then, what should I do?

Comment: `Breaking` means ceasing to work. Did you mean `Braking`?

Comment: Off course, sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Lots of native English speakers get it wrong -- in fact I've seen the same misspelling on several SO questions recently!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++1x (the new version of C++ that was standardised last year), you can use [strongly typed enumerations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations), which put the identifiers in the scope of the enum class itself (among other improvements).  These are declared with `enum class`:

```
class GameCharacter {
public:
    enum class State {
        Running,
        Walking,
        Stopped    // Referred to as GameCharacter::MovingState::Stopped.
    };
    ...
};
```

In the meantime, if you're stuck with a C++03 compiler or want to retain compatibility, just use `class` instead of `namespace` and declare the constructor private as you suggested in your own answer.  You can make the entire `class` private if the outside world doesn't need to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using new C++11 feature - [strongly typed enumerations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Strongly_typed_enumerations). Thanks to it you will not have name collisions and you will end up with really strong type system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use enum class for this

```
enum class State
{
    Accelerating,
    Breaking,
    Stopped
};
```

Then you'd refer to it as State::Breaking as you wanted.
This of course requires c++11, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations

Answer (score 2):

An alternative I found was to, instead of namespace, use classes, but the problem is this way the project is not clear enough and classes can be instantiated. (Although I can cheat this problem with private constructors)

```
class GameCharacter {
public:
    class MovingState {
        MovingState();
            /* or, in C++11:
             * MovingState() = delete;
             */
    public:
        enum State {
            Running,
            Walking,
            Stopped    // Referred as GameCharacter::MovingState::Stopped.
        };
    };
    class DrivingState {
        DrivingState();
            /* or, in C++11:
             * DrivingState() = delete;
             */
    public:
        enum State {
            Accelerating,
            Breaking,
            Stopped    // Referred as GameCharacter::DrivingState::Stopped.
        };
    };
    ...
};
```

this works, but I'm not very clear if this is the best solution. I think there should be another way. I want opinions. What do you think?

Comment: +1 This is the common solution in C++03, before strongly typed enums in C++11

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for C++11's [Strongly Typed Enumerations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations).

```
class GameCharacter {
public:
    enum class MovingState {
        Running,
        Walking,
        Stopped
    };
    ...
    void f(Movingstate m) { if (m == MovingState;:Running) ... }
};
void f() { if (mm == GameCharacter::MovingState::Running) ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use C++11, you can use

```
class GameCharacter {
 public:
  enum class DrivingState { Accelerating, Breaking, Stopped };
  enum class WalkingState { Stopped, Running, Walking };

  DrivingState driving_state() { return ds_; }
  void set_driving_state(DrivingState ds) { ds_ = ds; }

  WalkingState walking_state() { return ws_; }
  void set_walking_state(WalkingState ws) { ws_ = ws; }

  DrivingState ds_;
  WalkingState ws_;
};

int main() {
  GameCharacter g;
  g.set_walking_state(GameCharacter::WalkingState::Stopped);
  g.set_driving_state(GameCharacter::DrivingState::Stopped);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a struct instead of a namespace if you are unable to use C++11 [strongly typed enums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Strongly_typed_enumerations):

```
class GameCharacter {
public:
    struct MovingState {
        enum Enum {
            Running,
            Walking,
            Stopped
        };
    }
    ...
};
```

This was something that we adopted for a while (until C++11 support) as it can be used everywhere unlike the namespace trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have so much in your class that you feel you need to sub-categorise it into namespaces, then your class *has too many things*.

You should move stuff out of it. In particular all these enums don't need to be members of a class. Why not keep them in the same namespace that the class is in?

Comment: GRASP Patterns. Does not make sense moving the enum away if it is used only in that class.
EDIT: Also, just because a class have too much things does not necessarily means that it was bad designed. Classes can have a lot of responsibilities.

Comment: @LeonardoRaele: Not necessarily. Sounds like a case of lumping everything into an object just because some design pattern told you to. You are in fact giving your object _too much responsibility_ by owning all these types. They belong in a namespace. You can make it so that it's a namespace containing only these enums and that class, if it makes you feel better...

Comment: `Also, just because a class have too much things does not necessarily means that it was bad designed.` Yes, by definition of "too much", that is _precisely_ what it means.