# Namespace Functions within Class alternatives?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I'd like to be able to group similar functions in a class into a group so I don't need to append each name with what it's about.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484387/why-cant-we-declare-a-namespace-within-a-class) which says that you can't have namespaces within classes. I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273873/what-is-a-good-alternative-to-namespaces-within-classes) which proposes using strongly typed enums. The problem here though, is that I'm not sure whether or not these enums can actually accomodate functions?

**The problem contextualised:**

```
class Semaphore
{
public:

    void Set(bool State){Semaphore = State;}
    bool Get(){return Semaphore;}
    void Wait()
    {
        while (Semaphore)
        {
            //Wait until the node becomes available.
        }
        return;
    }
private:
    bool Semaphore      = 0;            //Don't operate on the same target simultaneously.
};

class Node : Semaphore
{
public:
    unsigned long IP    = 0;            //IP should be stored in network order.
    bool IsNeighbour    = 0;            //Single hop.

    std::vector<int> OpenPorts;
    //Rest of code...
};
```

Currently, `NodeClass.Get()` is how I can get the semaphore. However this introduces confusion as to what `Get()` actually gets. I'd like to have something akin to `NodeClass.Semaphore::Get()`. Otherwise I'd have to have the functions as `SemaphoreSet()`, `SemaphoreGet()`, and `SemaphoreWait()`, which isn't too well organised or nice looking.

I had thought of just having the `Semaphore` class on it's own, and instantiating it within the other classes, but if I could stick with the inheritance approach, that would be nicer.

So essentially, **is it possible to access inherited methods like `InheritedClass.Group::Function()`?**

Comment: Why does Node inherit from Semaphore? This is important.

Comment: @immibis I need each node to have semaphore functionality. But the semaphore itself needs manipulating.

Comment: "I need each node to have semaphore functionality" - so why do you need Node to inherit from Semaphore, as opposed to having a Semaphore as a member: `Semaphore MySemaphore;`?

Comment: I could do that I suppose, I'll have a think about it!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you could force the user to call with the base class name by `delete`ing the member function in the subclass:

```
class Base {
  public:
    void Set(bool) { }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    void Set(bool) = delete;
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    // d.Set(true); // compiler error
    d.Base::Set(true);
}
```

However, if the semantics of calling `Set` on the subclass are significantly different than what you'd expect them to be when calling `Set` on the base class, you should probably use a data member and name a member function accordingly as you've described:

```
class Base {
  public:
    void Set(bool) { }
};

class Derived {
  public:
    void SetBase(bool b) {
        b_.Set(b);
    }
  private:
    Base b_;
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.SetBase(true);
}
```